# Perl Net::SSH::Expect not printing out all expected output

Tags: perl

I am using expect in perl to get interface information from my router.  When I run the command on the remote router its missing about 10-15 lines that should be there.  Not sure why its stopping, any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

#use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => "10.10.10.10",
        user => 'user',
        password => 'pass'
        );
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
        if ($login_output !~ /router#/) {
            die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
        }
#$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";
$ssh->send("show int g2/1");
my $line;

while (defined ($line = $ssh->read_line()) ) {
        print $line."\n";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible `read_line()` is timing out after the default 1 second even though the router will send more information after that second?

Comment: I don't think so, it prints out lines then pauses and stops.  I tried adding a timeout variable but no dice...

Comment: 1. Is STDERR being captured? If you ssh directly to the router and run 'show int g2/1 > /dev/null'.  Is anything still printed to screen?  2. Is the output using different terminators on different lines?

Answer (score 1):

Net::SSH::Expect is not reliable. Use other module as [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2), [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny) or just [Expect](https://metacpan.org/module/Expect)

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("10.10.10.10",
                            user => 'user',
                            password => 'pass',
                            timeout => 60 );

my $output = $ssh->capture('show int g2/1');

# or for some non-conforming SSH server implementations rather
# common in network equipment you will have to do...
my $output = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => "show int g2/1\n"});

$ssh->error and die "unable to run remote command: " . $ssh->error;
```

Comment: Thanks salva this was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect since you are dealing with a router, you want to enable raw_pty => 1 like the [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod#IMPORTANT_NOTES_ABOUT_DEALING_WITH_SSH_AND_PSEUDO-TERMINALS) documentation suggests. Also, it might be easier for you to use the ->exec calls instead of the ->send + read_line.

For debugging further, pass in the log_stdout to the Net::SSH::Expect constructor and see if you can detect anything awry happening. Why did you comment out 'use strict'? Always 'use strict' and 'use warnings'